# iOS dev - referencing js files from settings root.plist

Tags: cocoa-touch

Inside my webviewcontroller.m file I reference external JS and CSS files to be used to manipulate the content I pull into the WebViewUI.

I can reference external files using;

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"var script = document.createElement('script');"
 "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
 "script.src = 'http://xxx/xxx.js';"
 "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];
```

But I keep having problems with referencing file paths using the settings root.plist;

```
NSString *JSStr = @"var script = document.createElement('script');"
    "script.type = 'text/javascript';";
    JSStr = [JSStr stringByAppendingString:[defaults stringForKey:@"overridejspath" ]];
    JSStr = [ JSStr stringByAppendingString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JSStr];
```

I can successfully reference CSS files using a similar method, but not JS files. Can you help?

Comment: What do you get with `NSLog(@"%@", JSStr);`?

Comment: var script = document.createElement('script');script.type = 'text/javascript';http://xxx/xxx.jsdocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

Comment: Got it :-) NSString *JSStr = @"var script = document.createElement('script');"
        "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
        "script.src = '";
        JSStr = [JSStr stringByAppendingString:[defaults stringForKey:@"overridejspath" ]];
        JSStr = [JSStr stringByAppendingString:@"';"];
        JSStr = [ JSStr stringByAppendingString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JSStr];